# How to write the output of a shader into a texture w/ ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm trying to write a fragment shader that can access it's own output from a previous point in time.

I know how to pass a texture to the shader as an uniform variable. 
But how can I write the output of the shader into a texture, so I can update it?

Comment: That is called 'ping-ponging'. See, for example, http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_water.html or http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html. Also, study how `EffectComposer` works in post-processing.